# Unable to search Sublime editor folder files

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am new to Sublime, used to using Dreamweaver as my web editor. I have my project folder open in the `Sublime Text 3` and I need to search all the files for a particular link `https://test.com`. From what I found on the web I need to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, enter my search string and then in `Where:` type the folder path I want to search. I have done that but the result set is empty even though I know the string I am searching for is there multiple times.

I tried entering the full path: `W:\Web\App1` (where App1 is the folder I have opened as the project folder) as well as `App1` but nothing gets returned. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible reasons a search might not match are if you have regex turned on when you didn't intend to, or had it off when you meant to have it on, or you have case sensitivity turned on and didn't match the case exactly, or if you have "match whole worlds only" turned on/off in error.

Comment: where can I change this setting? If I go to Preferences on the menu and then to Settings, it just opens a new Sublime text window

Comment: They're buttons to the left of the find panel; hover your mouse over the icons to see which ones are which.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, you can right-click on the folder you want to search in, then choose '*Find in Folder*'

[image]

In the bottom 'Find' box, make sure to have the 'Find options buttons' (on the left of the image) correctly set.

[image]

This is a very powerful option I use very often. Now I've tested in my SublimeText3 to look for an url like the one you provide and it works fine, as usual. With this setup:

Regular Expression: Off, Case Sensitive: Off, Whole Words: Off
...but this options are pretty straightforward and shouldn't affect your basic searches.